# Why am i getting this value-error? ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 4]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I receive this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 4]
```

My code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error , r2_score

data = load_boston()
boston = pd.DataFrame(data.data , columns=data.feature_names)
boston.columns = boston.columns.str.lower()
boston['medv'] = data['target']
x = boston.lstat
y = boston.medv
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred = model.predict(x_test)
mean_squared_error('y_test','pred')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
mean_squared_error('y_test','pred')
```

To

```
mean_squared_error(y_test,pred)
```

You compare strings instead of predictions and labels. Yet you do not assign this MSE value calculated, do not print it etc., you might want to do something with this calculated value.

Comment: Thanks and understood. And yes its just a part of training course assignment. Will print it only.
One more doubt. Suppose we do log adj to medv and sqrt adj to lstat what shall i do during mse calculation? should i exp it or square the y_test and pred values???